# Slicing to reverse part of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list, of which I want to extract a subslice from back to end. With two lines of code, this is

```
mylist = [...]
mysublist = mylist[begin:end]
mysublist = mysublist[::-1]
```

Is there a slicing notation to get the same effect in one line? This

```
mysublist = mylist[end:begin:-1]
```

is incorrect, because it includes the `end` and excludes the `begin` elements. This

```
mysublist = mylist[end-1:begin-1:-1]
```

fails when `begin` is 0, because `begin-1` is now `-1` which is interpreted as the index of the last element of `mylist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `None` if `begin` is `0`:

```
mysublist = mylist[end - 1:None if not begin else begin - 1:-1]
```

`None` means 'default', the same thing as omitting a value.

You can always put the conditional expression on a separate line:

```
start, stop, step = end - 1, None if not begin else begin - 1, -1
mysublist = mylist[start:stop:step]
```

Demo:

```
>>> mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'eggs']
>>> begin, end = 1, 3
>>> mylist[end - 1:None if not begin else begin - 1:-1]
['baz', 'bar']
>>> begin, end = 0, 3
>>> mylist[end - 1:None if not begin else begin - 1:-1]
['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply collapse your two lines into one:

```
mysublist = mylist[begin:end][::-1]
```

Comment: This still creates *two* list objects however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it does, but it depends what you're trying to optimize.  The mission was to do it "in one line" so I assume readability trumps efficiency.  Your solution with the ternary operator is technically unassailable, but I would find it unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the power of functional transformations:

```
mysublist = list(reversed(mylist[begin:end]))
```

Comment: `reversed()` doesn't return a list, it returns an *iterator*.