# How to reverse a part of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

I have the next list:

```
abclist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

With the above list I how to create the next one?

```
Reversed_part = ['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e']
```

Only the first 3 items are reversed and the last two stay in the same order.

Comment: Select the part that you want to reverse (by slicing), reverse it, then combine with the other unreversed parts.

Comment: `rev = abclist[3::-1] + abclist[3:]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse a part (slice) of a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647368/how-do-i-reverse-a-part-slice-of-a-list-in-python). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257249/how-do-i-reverse-a-sublist-in-a-list-in-place) and possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506123/slicing-to-reverse-part-of-a-list-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

def partial_reverse(lst, start, end):

    """Indexing (start/end) inputs begins at 0 and are inclusive."""

    return lst[:start] + lst[start:end+1][::-1] + lst[end+1:]

partial_reverse(lst, 0, 2)  # ['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a combination of  `reversed` method & `string slicing`

**Ex:**

```
abclist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(list(reversed(abclist[:3]))+abclist[-2:])
```

**Output:**

```
['c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abclist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
quantityToReverse = 3
remainder = len(abclist) - quantityToReverse
reverseArray = list(reversed(abclist[:quantityToReverse]))+abclist[-remainder:]

print(reverseArray)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answers usually benefit from an explanation, what the code does. This helps the OP to understand the answer and attracts more upvotes.